# Does it make a difference where I root a FileServer?

Tags: go, webserver, httprequest

At https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go, there's an example of a static file server serving sites in a single directory: `static`.

```
File: app.go
...
func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

However, I've found that I can get the same results with the following.

```
func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")) // root at the root directory.
  http.Handle("/static/", fs) //leave off the StripPrefix call.

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Are there any (performanace or security) downsides to doing it this way?  I can see that I'd have to use `StripPrefix` if my location of the files on the filesystem did not match the URL they were served at, but in this case it seems as though the call to `StripPrefix` is unnecessary.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, but I've had a look into this myself.  Performance-wise, it doesn't seem to be a problem, since the call to `FileServer` doesn't actually load the files into memory; it just stores away the address.  Security-wise, this seems to be exactly the same: I attempted a directory-traversal attack using something like the following.

```
$ curl -i --path-as-is 'http://localhost:3000/static/../sensitive.txt'
```

but I got a 301 response with both versions, which surprised me a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's same when you use `http.ServeMux` handler

`http.ServeMux` will call cleanPath function before match path

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2305

```
func (mux *ServeMux) Handler(r *Request) (h Handler, pattern string) {
// snip
    path := cleanPath(r.URL.Path)
//snip
}
```

cleanPath function return the canonical path for p, eliminating . and .. elements.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2174-L2193

```
// cleanPath returns the canonical path for p, eliminating . and .. elements.

func cleanPath(p string) string {
    if p == "" {
        return "/"
    }
    if p[0] != '/' {
        p = "/" + p
    }
    np := path.Clean(p)
    // path.Clean removes trailing slash except for root;
    // put the trailing slash back if necessary.
    if p[len(p)-1] == '/' && np != "/" {
        // Fast path for common case of p being the string we want:
        if len(p) == len(np)+1 && strings.HasPrefix(p, np) {
            np = p
        } else {
            np += "/"
        }
    }
    return np
}
```